# .map equivalent of .forEach to create an object

Tags: javascript

The following code populates an object called `result` with the values in `keys` as the keys and an empty string as each key's value.  This is working as desired.

```
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const result = {};
keys.forEach(key => {
  result[key] = '';
});
console.log(result);
```

[image]

However, I'm wondering if the `result` object can be created in a single command by using `.map`.  Below is what I've tried but it yields an array of objects rather than a single object.

```
const result = keys.map(key => ({
  [key]: ''
}));
console.log(result);
```

[image]

Comment: `.map()` always creates a new array that is in 1:1 relation with the old one. An array with X elements is definitely not the same as an object with X properties. You *could* still use `.map()` but not as the sole thing to create the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine `Object.fromEntries` and `map` methods. With `map` you can get array of `[key, value]` pairs and then by calling `fromEntries` you get an object from that array.

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => ([k, ''])))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach that only needs one method. ([`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

```js
const keys = ["one", "two", "three"];

const result = keys.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c]: "" }), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It seems like my question was trivial so I deleted it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use your map, then reduce:

```js
keys
  .map(k => ({[k]: ""}))
  .reduce((x, r) => ({...x, ...r}), {})
```

Comment: Yeah, well copy-pasted ;)

Comment: what did I copied ?

Comment: Oh, well it was legit but ok, let's remove it then ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Behemoth:  That's a very, very common pattern (even if [not very performant](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern)) and is more likely to have been answered independently rather than copied.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet Check out the edits and you'll understand. I really wouldn't care at all... but if it's the exact same snippet with altered variable names...

Comment: @Behemoth, I would likely have answered exactly the same way, modulo white space and variable names, without ever seeing either of these answers.  (I would probably have then pointed to the performance article mentioned, and pointed out that in a tight loop, that might be important.)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to transform an array into another object, it is usefull to use reduce.
I think this is more in line with your needs.
The trick is when you iterate over the accumulator and you want to modify with an assignment, the assignment returns undefined. But you need to return an object. Undefined or the modified object is the modified object. And you can continue adding keys.

```js
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
result = keys.reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = '') || obj, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note that this only works because the empty string you're using as a property value is false-y.  `keys.reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = 42) || obj, {})` would fail.  You could use a comma operator instead of `||`, or you could give up the single-expression callback in favor of a multi-statement body, or you could use the `.reduce((x, r) => ({...x, ...r}), {})` from other answers (if performance is not a [major concern](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern).)